# Android Shortcuts - App isn't installed error even though targetPackage and targetClass are correct

Tags: android, android-appshortcut

I tried implementing the Android Shortcuts when holding the icons in the home screen. But when I try to launch them I get an

> "App isn't installed" Toast

This is my `shortcuts.xml`:

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <shortcut
        android:icon="@drawable/plus_black"
        android:shortcutId="add_sub"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/shortcut_add_sub_long"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/shortcut_add_sub">

        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetClass="com.dancam.subscriptions.AddSubscription.AddSubscription"
            android:targetPackage="com.dancam.subscriptions.AddSubscription" />
    </shortcut>

    <shortcut
        android:icon="@drawable/pen"
        android:shortcutId="create_sub"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/shortcut_create_sub_long"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/shortcut_create_sub">

        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetClass="com.dancam.subscriptions.CreateSubscription.CreateSubscription"
            android:targetPackage="com.dancam.subscriptions.CreateSubscription" />
    </shortcut>
</shortcuts>
```

I have already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134639/app-isn%C2%B4t-installed-error-when-tapping-app-shortcut-in-nougat-7-1-1) but I couldn't find a suitable solution.

This is how my package/class tree looks like:

[image: file tree]

Any clue on how to fix this?

Comment: Replace both `android:targetPackage` attribute values with your `applicationId` and see if that helps.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks this worked but why does it require the `applicationId` instead of the actual package as the name suggests?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace both `android:targetPackage` attribute values with your `applicationId`.

Here, "package" refers to the `applicationId` (a.k.a., package name), not the Java package of the class.

Comment: How to handle if there are multiple flavors? `${applicationId}` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @SrikarReddy: I do not know what "doesn't seem to work" means. You might want to ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.

Comment: I'm getting "App isn't installed" Toast when I use `${applicationId}` as `android:targetPackage="${applicationId}"`.

Comment: I've `debug` and `release` buildtypes. So the target package names should be `android:targetPackage="com.company.app.debug”` and for release builds it should be `android:targetPackage=“com.company.app”` but I can’t dynamically set the required `targetPackage` using `android:targetPackage="${applicationId}”`.

Comment: @SrikarReddy: Ah, I understand. `${applicationId}` is a manifest feature, not for resources. So, have different versions of this shortcut XML in your `debug/` and `release/` source sets.